# How can prove this inequality $|\tau|^{2\gamma} \leq c_5(\gamma) \frac{1+|\tau|}{1+|\tau|^{1-2\gamma}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

I'm reading a demonstration that uses this following inequality. For a fixed $\gamma<1/4$, exists a $c_5(\gamma)$, such that

$|\tau|^{2\gamma} \leq c_5(\gamma) \frac{1+|\tau|}{1+|\tau|^{1-2\gamma}}, \forall \tau \in \mathbb{R}$.

I tried to deduce that using the fact that $0<\frac{1}{1+|\tau|}\leq1$, but i couldn't get in anywhere.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Reorganizing, this is equivalent to proving that the function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
f(\tau) = \frac{|\tau|+|\tau|^{2\gamma}} {|\tau|+1}
$$
is bounded. Note that it is continuous, and $\lim_{+\infty} f = \lim_{-\infty} f = 1$ (using the fact that $2\gamma <1$); therefore, it is bounded.

Comment: (also, as shown in this proof, the result holds for $\gamma < 1/2$, not only $\gamma<1/4$.)

Comment: Actually it will not hold for $\gamma < 1/2$, the reason why it holds is because $2\gamma<1-2\gamma$ when $\gamma < 1/4$. I figured this, but it wasn't suffice to prove that. But thank you so much for help me.

Comment: @JoãoPauloAndrade Glad it helped, but -- it **does** hold for all $\gamma \leq 1/2$ (the case $1/2$ is proven similarly, but the limit of $f$ at $\infty$ is $2$, not 1).

Comment: For instance, for $\gamma=1/2$, take $c_5(1/2)=2$. You have $$|\tau| \leq 2\cdot \frac{1+|\tau|}{2}$$ for all $\tau$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $|\tau| = x \geq 0$ and Consider: 
$$f(x) = \dfrac{x^{2\gamma}+x}{1+x}$$
and prove this has a maximum by taking derivative.